# Return the root partition name with lsblk or similar when the partition is encrypted

Tags: shell-script, scripting, cryptsetup, lsblk

This is my `lsblk` output:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1       259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0   512M  0 part  /efi
├─nvme0n1p2   259:2    0   420G  0 part  
│ └─cryptroot 254:0    0   420G  0 crypt /
└─nvme0n1p3   259:3    0  45.3G  0 part
```

I need to retrieve the "part" whose "crypt" is associated to the mountpoint "/", without knowing the "crypt" or the "part" beforehand:

```
nvme0n1p2 /
```

Can this be achieved in a single command?

Answer (score 0):

`lsblk` can output JSON which you can pipe to [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/).  `jq` is a JSON processor and you can do any number of complex queries with it.  So something like this should work:

```
lsblk --json | \
  jq -r '.blockdevices[] | .children[] | select( .. | objects | .mountpoints[]? == "/" ) | .name'
```

For example:

```bash
$ lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1             259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1         259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2         259:2    0   3.9G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3         259:3    0 949.5G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt 253:0    0 949.5G  0 crypt /

$ lsblk --json | \
  jq -r '.blockdevices[] | .children[] | select( .. | objects | .mountpoints[]? == "/" ) | .name'
nvme0n1p3
```